# Timezone problem with ggpubr when loading factoextra package

Tags: r, package

I installed factoextra on R studio version 0.99.473 for macs, however, it didn't load the package ggubpr, because cowplot isn't available due to what it says is an unknown time zone. I have no idea what this means. Below is the warning message:

install.packages("factoextra")
Installing package into ‘/Users/emilystewart/Library/R/3.2/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
dependencies ‘car’, ‘cowplot’ are not available
also installing the dependencies ‘FactoMineR’, ‘ggpubr’

Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2019a.1.0/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles'
ERROR: dependency ‘car’ is not available for package ‘FactoMineR’

removing ‘/Users/emilystewart/Library/R/3.2/library/FactoMineR’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘FactoMineR’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2019a.1.0/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles'
ERROR: dependency ‘cowplot’ is not available for package ‘ggpubr’
removing ‘/Users/emilystewart/Library/R/3.2/library/ggpubr’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘ggpubr’ had non-zero exit status

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You might try updating R, then updating all the relevant packages.

Comment: Ok, I think the issue may be with the cowplot package. I did update R studio for mac to the latest version, 1.2.1335, however, I get this warning when I try to install cowplot:  

package ‘cowplot’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)

It says I have R version 3.2.2. I don't understand the connection between the different R vs. R studio versions. Shouldn't it give me a higher version of R, if I'm using the most recent R studio version for Mac?

Comment: Rstudio does not update R. You have to do that separately. Then, btw, your packages will be in the old version directory, so it's sometimes helpful to drag them over to wherever the Mac installation keeps the new ones.

Comment: Ok, thanks I will try that.